# Merge repeating smarty section into 1

Tags: php, smarty

I cant change the array which is passed into Smarty although at the moment I have:

```
{if $cms.featured && $cms.featured.haspictures}
{foreach from=$cms.featured.pictures key=id item=row name=foo}
{if $id eq 0}
<div class="sliderkit-panel">
    <a href="{$cms.featured.url}" title="{$cms.featured.title|truncate:60}"><img src="{$HOME}/get/wide{$row.filename}" alt="{if $row.description}{$row.description}{else}{$cms.featured.title}{/if}" /></a>
</div>
{/if}
{/foreach}
{/if}

{if $cms.featured1 && $cms.featured1.haspictures}
{foreach from=$cms.featured1.pictures key=id item=row name=foo}
{if $id eq 0}
<div class="sliderkit-panel">
    <a href="{$cms.featured1.url}" title="{$cms.featured1.title|truncate:60}"><img src="{$HOME}/get/wide{$row.filename}" alt="{if $row.description}{$row.description}{else}{$cms.featured1.title}{/if}" /></a>
</div>
{/if}
{/foreach}
{/if}

{if $cms.featured2 && $cms.featured2.haspictures}
{foreach from=$cms.featured2.pictures key=id item=row name=foo}
{if $id eq 0}
<div class="sliderkit-panel">
    <a href="{$cms.featured2.url}" title="{$cms.featured2.title|truncate:60}"><img src="{$HOME}/get/wide{$row.filename}" alt="{if $row.description}{$row.description}{else}{$cms.featured2.title}{/if}" /></a>
</div>
{/if}
{/foreach}
{/if}
```

Is there anyway I can reduce this repeated code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enclosing the repeated function in a {for} loop and using a variable as the array index, something like

```
{for $loop=1 to 3}
  {$featured='featured'}
  {if $loop!=1}{$featured=$featured|cat:$loop}{/if}

  {if $cms.$featured && $cms.$featured.haspictures}
  ....


{/for}
```